# SEO friendly URLs - from blog.php?articleId=26 to blog/$articleTitle

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, seo

After finally getting my code to post a URL-friendly title to my db (for later use as the SEO optimised URL) I am now looking at how to get my blog script to accept said URL.

Ideally I would like my URLS to appear in a similar way to stack overflows.

Currently my URLs are like this:

```
blog.php?action=viewArticle&articleId=26
```

I want it to appear like this:

```
/blog/responsive-layout-design/
```

I have sorted out one side of the script - the side that create the new URL, and saves it in the database but I'm struggling to work out how to implement that on the front end.

I have looked at a few guides and examples dotted around but they only show how to create a URL such as:

```
store.php?action=viewItem&itemID=34 to store/item/34
```

Obviously, I could do this fairly easily with my URLs, but it's still just going to be displaying an article id, rather than the article title.

This is my current code for pulling articles from the database by ID - how would this be modified to gain the functionality I'm looking for?

```
function viewArticle() { 
   if ( !isset($_GET["articleId"]) || !$_GET["articleId"] ) { homepage(); return; } 
   $results = array(); 
   $results['article'] = Article::getById( (int)$_GET["articleId"] );      
   $results['pageTitle'] = $results['article']->title . " | Blog"; 
   require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/viewArticle.php" ); 
}
```

Comment: Why don´t you use a framework? So routing would be easy as "Route::get("store/item", function($id){ echo "product id: ".$id; }); more at http://laravel.com/docs/routing

Answer (score 1):

The way I've always done it is set the URL slug in the database.

So you'll store something like:

```
tblBlog
blogID | blogTitle | blogContent | blogURLSlug
```

You'd then set up pretty URLs using .htaccess

```
RewriteRule   ^/(blog)/(.*)/$   /blog.php?slug=$2
```

When selecting the page content out, select using the URLSlug instead

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `blogTitle`, `blogContent` FROM `tblBlog` WHERE `blogURLSlug` = :slug");
$stmt->bindParam(':slug', $_GET['slug']);
$stmt->execute();
$blogData = $stmt->fetch();
```

This way, you can visit `/blog/RWD-is-cool/` and it will select from the DB where the URLSlug = `RWD-is-cool`

Comment: Thanks for your help @DaryllDoyle I have added my getbyID code to the question - after seeing that - do you think this will be easy to implement?

Comment: Hi @Jack, Yes, shouldn't be too hard to implement with some minor changes to that function. Firstly, you'd have to change `Article::getById()` to `Article::getBySlug()` and then change all the references to `$_GET['articleId']` to `$_GET['articleSlug']` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need databases to do that. All php frameworks ( that I know of ) support this type of urls and the method used to recognize what is what is called routing. Basically the structure of an url is the following `www.website.com/controller(page)/method/getparameters`. What you use to access this as such is a single entry point. In other words you only have 1 `index.php` file in the root directory and you redirect all calls to it, then break down the URL into its given components and decide what to do from there on. A simple example with apache:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,NS]
```

index.php

```
$page = str_replace('index.php','', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$page = str_replace($page,'',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$page = explode('/',$page );
$controller = array_shift($page );
$parameters = array();
foreach ($page as $val){
    $parameters[] = urldecode($val);
}
```

Then in the url `www.website.com/blog/responsive-layout-design/` you will have

```
$controller => 'blog'
$parameters => array(
    0 => 'responsive-layout-design',
    1 => ''
)
```

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: Thanks @php_nub_qq - I have added a section of code to the original question that I believe needs to be edited - would you have any idea how this would work?

Comment: @Jack Oh, well in order to do this your article titles must be unique. Then instead of passing the `id` in the URL you'll be passing the title and select based on it the same way you select based on the id.